# Error URL segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created my own login page and social media (Facebook) with Codeigniter 2.1.2, then I wanted to use url redirect, for example:

```
http://mydomain.com/account/login/redirect_url/login/http://mydomain.com/
1- redirect_url  // is a Method in account controllers
2- login         // parameter define login or logout,when click link login/logout
3- http://mydomain.com/ // Is the url for redirecting to, after login succeed.
```

In my localhost it's working well, but on my server it's not working. I know some reasons why does it work, because of `.htaccess` file

Local:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Server:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I think that, cause by Question mark(?), Even facebook login is not working also. But I tried the code without `?` on the server, but it doesn't work at all, if I use `?` works all, but url only.

My question is what should I do with this code?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` seems wrong. I'd think either that `?` or the `/` should go.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that many CodeIgniter developers are not using the standard method that many sites use today.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L, QSA]
```

In essence, you'll find that there are many ways to do it, but I don't think that you really need to use the `./` and the `$1`.

I guess it also depends on what server system you are using.

Hope this helps. If not, perhaps you could show us your entire hypertext access file (.htaccess)?

Comment: Thank for all answer me, I would like to tell you that, this problem, I was solved already!, thank you for your consideration on me.

Comment: Glad to hear this - perhaps sharing your solution so that others may learn from it too?